# replacing a word or part of a word using a regexp in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, regex, replace

I have a string and I'd like to replace all instances of "blah" whether they form part of a word or not with "real".

So an input string like this:

```
"blah pleaseblahme nowblah"
```

would look like this after replacement occurs:

```
 "real pleaserealme nowreal"
```

Using word boundaries allows me to replace individual "blahs" but not "blahs" that are also parts of words. For example:

```
"blah pleaseblahme nowblah".replace(/\bblah\b/ig, "real")
```

only gives me:

```
"real pleaseblahme nowblah"
```

How can I satisfy both conditions of replacing blah as an individual word and as part of a word using the .replace() method in JavaScript?

Comment: Just stop using word boundaries... `str.replace(/blah/ig, 'real')`

Answer (score 1):

You pretty much answered your own question; stop using word boundaries in your regex:

```js
str.replace(/blah/ig, 'real');
```